# Android crash on restart app : java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class ; no empty constructor

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

My Android App crashes on restart after 12 hours' idle time.

I have been trying to add empty constructors everywhere (as the crash log told me to do so), but still fail.

Here is the crash log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(22225): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abcde.com/com.abcde.com.HomeActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.abcde.com.BaseSlideActivity$12: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2080)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4881)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:804)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:571)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.abcde.com.BaseSlideActivity$12: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:413)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1801)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:213)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.onCreate(SlidingFragmentActivity.java:23)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at com.abcde.com.BaseSlideActivity.onCreate(BaseSlideActivity.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at com.abcde.com.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:112)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5084)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2044)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(22225): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.abcde.com.BaseSlideActivity$12; no empty constructor
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
E/AndroidRuntime(22225):    ... 20 more
```

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseSlideActivity implements
    TutorialFragmentListener {
private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
public String mLastSelectedMenu = "";
// private Fragment mLastContentFragment = null;
private boolean isRestart;

private MenuData lastMenuData;
private List<String> fragmentNameHistory = new ArrayList<String>();

public int currentOrientation;
public float currentFontScale;
public static boolean isOrientationChanged = false;
public boolean isLanguageChanged = false;
public boolean isJumpToMycoupons = false;
public boolean isLogin;
public BocApplication application;
public FrameLayout layout_post;
public FrameLayout layout_pre;
public RelativeLayout layout_cover;

public static AQuery globalAQuery;
public static boolean isMainPageClicked;

public MenuFragmentAutoHighlighter menuFragmentAutoHighlighter;


boolean testPush = false;


public HomeActivity() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mTitleRes = R.string.home;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    menuFragmentAutoHighlighter = new MenuFragmentAutoHighlighter(this);


    Utils.mContext = getApplicationContext();
    Utils.getDisplayImageOptions(this);
    application = (BocApplication) getApplication();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            this).writeDebugLogs().build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    currentFontScale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;
    // mLastContentFragment = null;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    globalAQuery = new AQuery(this);

    layout_post = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.postlogon_content_frame);
    layout_pre = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    // layout_cover = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_cover);

    // Loading Mask
    makeLoadingMask();
    prepareOverlayWebView();
    // LoadingMask.getCurrentInstance().flushLoadingView().refresh();


    // VAN: PUSH CHECK SHOULD LAUNCH CERTAIN PAGE HERE!

    if (!checkPushNotificationLaunchPage())
    {   
        Fragment dashboardFragment = ContentFragmentHelper.getContentFragment(
                this, genHomeMenuData());
        changeFragment(dashboardFragment, null);
    }
    initDb();



    findViewById(R.id.view_overlay).setOnTouchListener(
            new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
                }
            });



    SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setOnClosedListener(menuClosedListener);


}
```

BaseSlideActivity.java

```
public class BaseSlideActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
protected int mTitleRes;

private View mFrameTitleButton;
private View mFrameEditButton;

private View mLeftMenuButton;
private View mBackButton;
private View mRightMenuButton;

protected View mLoginButton;
protected View mRightDivider;
protected View mDoneButton;
protected TextView mResetButton;
protected TextView mCancelButton;

protected TextView mLoginButtonTitle;
protected TextView mDoneButtonTitle;

public MenuFragment mLeftMenuFragment;
protected RightMenuFragment mRightMenuFragment;

protected ActionBarListener mActionBarDoneListener;
protected ActionBarListener mActionBarResetListener;
protected ActionBarListener mActionBarCancelListener;

public BaseSlideActivity() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // isTablet checking
    if (!Utils.isTablet(this)) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    initActionBar();
    setTitle(mTitleRes);
    initSlidingMenu(savedInstanceState);
}
```

SlidingFragmentActivity.java

```
public class SlidingFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements SlidingActivityBase {

private SlidingActivityHelper mHelper;

public SlidingFragmentActivity() {
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHelper = new SlidingActivityHelper(this);
    mHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onPostCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHelper.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Could someone give me some clues?

Update 2014/10/15 11:00AM: MenuFragmentAutoHighlighter.java

```
public class MenuFragmentAutoHighlighter {

public HomeActivity homeActivity;

public MenuFragmentAutoHighlighter(HomeActivity homeActivity)
{
    this.homeActivity = homeActivity;
}

public void tryHighlightMenuItemByBaseFragmentClass(Fragment fragment)
{
    if (homeActivity == null || homeActivity.mLeftMenuFragment == null)
    {
        return;
    }

        homeActivity.mLeftMenuFragment.setSelectedPreMenuItem(
                ContentFragmentHelper.MENU_HOME,
                null);
}
}
```

Comment: post `MenuFragmentAutoHighlighter` class

Comment: Notice this: Unable to instantiate fragment com.bochk.com.BaseSlideActivity$12, means you may have an inner Fragment class that is not static, if so, you should make it static and have a try.

Comment: I searched over my workspace, but no inner Fragment class is declared, neither static nor not.

Comment: The 13th anonymous inner class in `BaseSlideActivity` (`$12`, counting from 0) is the fragment that has no no-arg constructor.

Comment: $12 - that means  public MenuFragment mLeftMenuFragment;
protected RightMenuFragment mRightMenuFragment;   is it???

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

BaseSlideActivity's constructor (and also all the other constructors) you posted shouldnt be empty since this class extends SlidingFragmentActivity.
You should add a call in it (and also in all the other constructors of classes that extends other classes) a call:

```
super.CLASS_NAME(); //a call to the super class's empty constructor
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. I tried this solution earlier but no significant effects. Eventually I override onCreate(bundle) into super.onCreate(null)